# How to enable Named Pipes and TCP/IP in SQL Server LocalDB?

Tags: sql-server, localdb

Is it possible to enable the SQL Server network protocols *Named Pipes* and *TCP/IP* for *SQL Server LocalDB*? If yes, how can I do that?

Comment: You don't. It's called LocalDB for a reason; because it's local. Sounds like you're after SQL Server Express.

Answer (score -1):

You enable protocols using the SQL Server Configuration Manager:

[image]

Comment: This has no effect on LocalDB instances, which mostly ignore the global configuration altogether.